# HubConnection StartAsync in hosted Blazor Webassembly takes too long

Tags: c#, websocket, blazor, signalr, hosted-blazor-webassembly

I am working on a microservices project with a hosted blazor webassembly application all in a kubernetes cluster. In the Blazor Webassembly (**Hosted**) PWA I am using SignalR Hub for the communication between the Blazor.Client and Blazor.Server. When I call HubConnection.StartAsync sometimes it lasts a few milliseconds and sometimes up to **15 seconds**.

Usage and StartAsync-Call in Blazor.Client:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl( Navigator.ToAbsoluteUri( "/testhub" ), options =>
{
    options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
    options.SkipNegotiation = true;
})
.WithAutomaticReconnect()
.Build();

hubConnection.On<MyDataModel>( "ReceiveData", ( result ) => HandleData( result ) );

try
{
    // !! sometimes this call lasts up to 15 seconds !!
    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
}
catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
```

SignalR configuration in Program.cs in Blazor.Server:

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR( options =>
{
    options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 60 );
    options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 30 );
    options.MaximumParallelInvocationsPerClient = 3;
    options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 5 );
    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
} );

// Response compression for SignalR
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression( opts =>
{
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        new[] { "application/octet-stream" } );
} );
```

I played around with the configuration but with no effect. On my local workstation there is no problem, but deployed to the cloud this problem occurs. What can be the reason for this problem?

**Update**:

I found out that this problem occurs in chrome/edge browsers and not in firefox.

Comment: You are not getting a connection.  It may be the credentials are being checked by a Password Server and the server is not responding quickly.  It also could be a proxy and disabling the proxy may solve issue.  It probably is not your code but the network.  Normally issues when using a proxy the code will wait the timeout period and then try without the proxy.  Disabling the proxy usually solves issue.

Comment: Is the hosted application on IIS and is it set to be always running? If not then the delay could be the IIS app starting up. It would be sporadic since if you catch it when it's already on it'll be fast.

Comment: @jdweng There is no proxy but a load balancer and an ingress nginx controller on the cloud server. There shouldn't be a credential checking in starting the hubconnection. I'm not sure what is behind this method.

Comment: @JustAnswertheQuestion It runs in a kubernetes pod with mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 I think it runs with kestrel under linux.

Comment: @ibram : Windows always does a credential check when a connection is made.  It is part of the authentication.

Comment: @jdweng it is running in a linux system.

Comment: You still need authentication.  What type authentication is being used?

Comment: @jdweng I didn't use any authentication for the signalr connection between Blazor.Server and Blazor.Client. There are API calls from the Blazor.Server with jwt-securitytoken read out of the cookie but the Blazor app is using cookie auth.

Comment: Read item 3.  Python most be doing this while c# is not : https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/authentication.html?force_isolation=true